# gitlab markdown numbered & lettered lists

Tags: gitlab, markdown

The [gitlab markdown doc on lists](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#lists) shows a numbered list with lettered sub-lists. Here's a screenshot (look at number 3 in the formatted list: the sub-bullets have letters, not numbers):

[image: screenshot of gitlab docs]

It says that this is possible with:

```
1. Actual numbers don't matter, just that it's a number
   1. Ordered sub-list
   1. Next ordered sub-list item
```

But actually using that just produces numbered sub-lists (here and in gitlab).

1. Actual numbers don't matter, just that it's a number

   1. Ordered sub-list
   2. Next ordered sub-list item

Is it possible to get a list like:

1. Parent
   a. sub-list item 1
   b. sub-list item 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the GitLab documentation is wrong.

In their [Handbook Markdown Guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/#ordered-lists) there's another example that works like your code:

```
1. Item one
   1. Sub item one
   1. Sub item two
1. Item two
1. Item three
```

Output

```
1. Item one
   1. Sub item one
   2. Sub item two
2. Item two
3. Item three
```

I think I've found an open issue ([Docs feedback: misleading GLFM lists syntax](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/382034)) and it looks that the [latest code in master branch](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/user/markdown.md#lists) has been fixed

Answer (score 2):

lettered ordered lists are not a part of standard markdown. the letters will only appear when rendering the markdown using an markdown extension or by using CSS.

it should render with letters when viewed in gitlab, but not other places using standard markdown.

Comment: It does not show letters when rendered on Gitlab (hence my question). It shows numbers.

Comment: are you running gitlab locally? it could be a version issue. if not, then possibly an issue with web browser

Comment: It is a private (local) Gitlab instance, but Atxulo's answer shows that it's a typo in the documentation.